# Children of Button

Tags: c#, wpf

I have

```
<Button>
    <Grid>
       <TextBlock/>
       <Image/>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

I can access the button name with

```
tbUserSelection.Text = ((Button)sender).Name;
```

Is it also possible to access the text block's text this way?

Thanks

Philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find it in the `Grid`'s `Children` collection:

```
Button button = (Button)sender;
TextBlock textBlock = (button.Content as Grid)?.Children.OfType<TextBlock>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Just assign Name or x:Name and use that.